# Failed to connect to api.paypal.com port 443: Connection timed out

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

When I'm using *paypal vault API* to save my customer credit card numbers on paypal server so response like that live PayPal-PHP-SDK

```
[url:PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException:private] => https://api.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token
    [data] => 
    [message:protected] => Failed to connect to api.paypal.com port 443: Connection timed out
    [string:Exception:private] =>
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: i already using https:

Comment: Internal network problem, firewall, ... api.paypal.com answers on 443.

Comment: ringø can we discuss in personal chat message me please or contact via email 'waleed.aimviz@gmail.com' please i have to talk about this issue i have already check my port it 443 

echo $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']; // result 443

now br0o